# Ruby - Enumerable::group_by and empty string

Tags: arrays, ruby, group-by, grouping

I'm trying to group an array on single empty key in a service using `group_by` method like below

```
...

def process(array)
  if a_case
    partition = method(:general_entity)
  else
    partition = method(:other_entity)
  end

  array.group_by(&partition)
end

def general_entity(_cells)
  ""
end

def other_entity(_cells)
...
```

Do you think such an approach in `general_entity` method would be safe to use?

It would be great if you could share your thoughts or suggest a better approach :D

Comment: 1. The code above won’t work, `general_entity` must be of arity `1` or `-1`. 2. How is it different from `def process(array); {"" => array}; end`?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin 2. Oh sorry I forgot to mention that in actual code there are some other cases that are using the line `group_by` I stated in my question. So I have to use group_by. 1. Well it seems to be working with specs and all but just wanted to be sure. And I will update my questions for better explanation

Comment: _Sidenote:_ assign a result of `if` / `case` to `partition`: `partition = if ... else ... end`. Indeed, it’d work with arity `0` as well since the block is actually a proc, not lambda.

Comment: I would rewrite the whole `process` method as: `def process(array); array.group_by(&method(a_case ? :general_entity : :other_entity)); end`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thank you for your reply but what I'm actually worried about is that using `""` in `general_entity` method whether it's alright to use it in such way. But your approach for `process` method looks cool though :)

Comment: It’s perfectly OK, why?

Comment: Well I'm using such an approach for the first time and since I'm dealing with some invoices, I was worried whether it would cause to lose some items in the array somehow

Comment: Nothing in CS happens “somehow.” Ruby is open source, here is the implementation of [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) (click on toggle source) and you after all might check it yourself with `[1,1,1].group_by { "" }`.

Comment: Nice, good example, thanks a lot :D but can you write your last comment as an answer. I'd like to accept it.